# Python: assign boolean values to list elements given a certain condition

Tags: python, list, boolean

Say you have the following list:

```
import numpy as np

mylist=[8.4468975,
        8.52036,
        9.3605785,
        np.ma.core.MaskedConstant(),
        np.ma.core.MaskedConstant()]  

 # [8.4468975, 8.52036, 9.3605785, masked, masked]
```

and you want to assign `0` to all values that are `masked`, and `1` to all the others. How can you properly do it?

I've tried this, but the result is an empty list:

```
mylist=[1 for i,v in enumerate(mylist) if type(mylist[i]) is float]
```

The result should be numerical (no True/False):

```
mylist=[1,1,1,0,0]
```

**EDIT**

The `masked` values that are present in my original list are of the type `numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
mylist = [1 if isinstance(v, float) else 0 for i,v in enumerate(mylist)]
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
mylist = [0 if isinstance(v, np.ma.core.MaskedConstant) else 1 for i,v in enumerate(mylist)]
```

so that you only set to 0 a specific mask type.

The relevant function to check for the type of a variable is: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance

Moreover, as you (correctly) use the enumerate construct, you already looping over the values with variable v, so no need to access it doing mylist[i].

Comment: I had actually forgot an important thing regarding the type of the `masked` instances. They are `numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant`, and not strings. So your approach does not work the way it is now.

Comment: My approach should work anyway, since it does not rely on string comparison.

Comment: The result I get is a list of `0` values. Nothing else. I don't see why

Comment: Please try the second approach

Comment: What is `el`? It seems like it was not defined? Was it meant to be `else`?

Comment: simple typo, was supposed to be "v". Fixed now

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
mylist=[8.4468975,
        8.52036,
        9.3605785,
        masked,
        masked]

mylist = [0 if type(x) is numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant else 1 for x in mylist]
```

Also note that your list comprehension `mylist=[1 for i,v in enumerate(mylist) if type(mylist[i]) is float]` does not quite do what you describe; at least not in the general case. You are assigning `1` to anything that is not `float` which is not the same as to anything that is `'masked'`.

Also note that when looping like `[1 for i,v in enumerate(mylist) if type(mylist[i]) is float]` you are (*falsely though, see further down*) not using the `v` so you could rewrite as `[1 for i,_ in enumerate(mylist) if type(mylist[i]) is float]`. Notice the underscore. It is used to imply that you will be *dumping* the second item of the tuple returned by `enumerate()`.

Finally, i said falsely further up because in your list comprehension `mylist[i]` can be substituted by `v`. So properly done it would be written like: `[1 for v in mylist if type(v) is float]`. But as I said, this is slightly different from what you seem to want.

Comment: I had actually forgot an important thing regarding the type of the `masked` instances. They are `numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant`, and not strings. So your approach does not work the way it is now.

Comment: @CF84 Now your *workaround* makes more sense. I will read a bit on those and edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `int()` to cast your booleans to integers:

```
[int(isinstance(x,float)) for x in mylist]
```

Note this works because `numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant()` is not a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function here :

```
>>> list(map(lambda x : 0 if isinstance(x,np.ma.core.MaskedConstant) else 1 , mylist))

[1,1,1,0,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not see this answer that often therefore I give it despite the other answers are satisfactory. Define a function `f`

```
def f(x):
    if isinstance(x, np.ma.core.MaskedConstant):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Now do list comprehension

```
mylist = [f(x) for x in mylist]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful as it puts things into perspective and reminds me of the existence of functions. However, given the lengthy code I am working on, I find it more suitable to follow a list-comprehension approach.

Comment: @CF84 This is the list comprehension approach.